# Mockbean would not throw an error when called inside the test subject class

Tags: java, spring, mockito, spring-boot-test

Seems that the mockbean which returns void is not throwing an error when being called inside the test subject. I am able to call it outside and it would throw an error. Is there something wrong with how I am using it?

```
//some imports ...
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={ MessagingController.class })
public class MessagingControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MessagingController controller;

    @MockBean
    private RabbitMessagingTemplate rabbitMessagingTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testPublishMessageConversionException() {
        //given:
        Message message = new Message(null, null, null);

        //when:
        doThrow(MessageConversionException.class).when(rabbitMessagingTemplate).convertAndSend(any());
        ResponseEntity<?> response = controller.publish(message);
        // rabbitMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend() // this throws the error
        //then:
        assertThat(response).isNotNull();
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

        verify(rabbitMessagingTemplate).convertAndSend(message.getExchange(), message.getRoutingKey(), message.getPayload());
    }

 ...

}
```

Comment: Please provide more information regarding your problem. Maybe show a full test method and how you initialize the mock.

Comment: @Rozart, I added some more context, thanks!

Comment: Are there any annotations on `MessagingControllerTest` class? Did you try to debug the code that is supposed to throw an error, to see if it's actually using your mocked bean or a regular one?

Comment: @Rozart, yes I debugged it in intellij and confirmed that it's the same mocked bean inside and outside the controller.

Comment: I think the issue is that your `@SpringBootTest` annotation points to the controller you're trying to test, instead of the `@Configuration` class with your application context setup -  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#classes

Could you please try to remove `(classes={ MessagingController.class })` part from your `@SpringBootTest` annotation and rerun the test?

Comment: @Rozart, I'd get an error `No qualifying bean of type 'messaging.web.MessagingController' available` if I remove that part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184904/discussion-between-rozart-and-alegria).

Answer (score 2):

Why would you use a whole spring context if you are just trying to make a unit test? To my opinion the SpringRunner is very useful for integration and e2e tests, but for unit tests you should stick to the MockitoJUnitRunner. Something like this should work:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MessagingControllerTest {
    @Mock
    private RabbitMessagingTemplate rabbitMessagingTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private MessagingController controller;

    @Test
    public void testPublishMessageConversionException() {
        //given:
        Message message = mock(Message.class);

        //when:
        when(rabbitMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(anyObject()).thenThrow(new MessageConversionException());
        try {
            ResponseEntity<?> response = controller.publish(message);
            fail();
        } catch (MessageConversionException mce) {
            //then:
            assertThat(response).isNotNull();
            assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

            verify(rabbitMessagingTemplate, times(1)).convertAndSend(message.getExchange(), message.getRoutingKey(), message.getPayload());
        }
    }

 ...

}
```

Comment: Good point for not running the whole spring context! I applied it in my code! I'm new to Java unit testing. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that mocked bean is not being stubbed properly somehow. I have to use specific parameters. @Rozart also suggested using to do exceptions assertions http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#exception-assertion

Here's the working one:

```
@Test
    public void testPublishMessageConversionException() {
        //given:
        Message message = new Message("", "", "");

        //when:
        doThrow(MessageConversionException.class).when(rabbitMessagingTemplate).convertAndSend("","","");

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> { controller.publish(message); }).isInstanceOf(IllegalArgumentException.class)
                .hasMessageContaining("Unable to convert payload");
    }
```